# Multi-module gradle project: Unable to make calls to other module methods

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

[image: My Multi-ModuleProjectStructure looks like this]

My setting.gradle looks like this

```
rootProject.name = 'MainProject'
include 'ModuleA'
include 'ModuleB'
include 'ModuleC'
```

MainProject build.gradle  looks like this

```
 plugins {
   ................
}

subprojects {
    group = 'com.example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    apply plugin: "java"

    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()       
    }

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    dependencies {
       ...........
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {  
        .............
        }
    }

    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
}
```

ModuleA build.gradle is like

```
dependencies {
    .............
    compile(":ModuleB")
    compile(":ModuleC")
}
```

ModuleB build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    .............
}
```

Modulec build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    .............
}
```

So ModuleA has dependency on ModuleB
My requirement is like in ModuleA test class , i want to use ModuleB class to create object and make a call to ModuleB methods. So as do integration testing.

Issue i am facing is like , unable to import classes of ModuleB and ModuleC in ModuleA and create object to call their methods.Even after doing project level clean build.

Comment: The `dependencies` seem to be defined correctly. Maybe check that the classes you are trying to use are defined as `public` and then try to call clear and assemble on the maven project once again. (After doing that, please include the error you get)

Comment: The class is public

Comment: Has the same issue here
Unresolved dependency: project  abcProject